# url to be used for SVN client

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have set up an svn repository at a shared folder (z:\svn_repository)
 I have started the svn server as follows :

svnserve -d -r z:\svn_repository

Now I am using a svn client (tortoiseSVN) to access the repository.

tortoiseSVN is asking me for a url to be given. 
Question: what is the url that I should input to access z:\svn_repository.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- You **must not** use repository's directory as root-dir for `-r`, only parent(s) of repository
- Then you have `-r` option correctly specified, only part of path after root used in URL, hostname part is any IP|hostnames, on which svnserve listen ("all interfaces" by default)

For `svnserve -d -r z:\` your URL will be `svn://HOSTNAME/svn_repository`

[Read SVNBook carefully!](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html)